# yosemiteでpumaのgemがインストール出来ない。おそらくSSL周りのエラーですが、原因がわかりません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

$ which openssl
/usr/local/bin/openssl

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481

$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015

```
An error occurred while installing puma (2.11.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install puma -v '2.11.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

環境構築をする際に、pumaのインストールで躓いております。

調べていると似たような問題を抱えている人がいたため、それを元に実行していたのですが、
結果的にはダメでした。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465544/cannot-build-puma-gem-on-os-x-yosemite

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143180/puma-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294199/cannot-install-puma-gem-on-ruby-on-rails

ssl周りのエラーなのかと思い以下も実行しました。

$ brew link openssl --force
$ brew upgrade openssl

どなたか原因がわかる方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご助言いただけないでしょうか？

宜しくお願いします。

エラー文言

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing puma:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/home/sandbox/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... no
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssleay32... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/Users/home/sandbox/usr/bin/ruby
        --with-puma_http11-dir
        --without-puma_http11-dir
        --with-puma_http11-include
        --without-puma_http11-include=${puma_http11-dir}/include
        --with-puma_http11-lib
        --without-puma_http11-lib=${puma_http11-dir}/lib
        --with-ssllib
        --without-ssllib
        --with-ssleay32lib
        --without-ssleay32lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/home/sandbox/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.10.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/home/sandbox/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0/puma-2.10.2/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらの環境ではEl capitan + Ruby 2.0.0-p481でpuma 2.11.0をインストールしようとしたところ、以下のエラーが出ました。

```
$ gem install puma -v '2.11.0'
Fetching: rack-1.6.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-1.6.4
Fetching: puma-2.11.0.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing puma:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/jit/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling http11_parser.c
compiling io_buffer.c
io_buffer.c:119:21: warning: passing 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') to parameter of type 'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
  return rb_str_new(b->top, b->cur - b->top);
                    ^~~~~~
/Users/jit/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:674:29: note: passing argument to parameter here
VALUE rb_str_new(const char*, long);
                            ^
1 warning generated.
compiling mini_ssl.c
In file included from mini_ssl.c:3:
/Users/jit/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward/rubyio.h:2:2: warning: use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h" [-W#warnings]
#warning use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h"
 ^
mini_ssl.c:4:10: fatal error: 'openssl/bio.h' file not found
#include <openssl/bio.h>
         ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [mini_ssl.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jit/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jit/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.0/ext/puma_http11/gem_make.out
```

しかし、最新の2.15.3は問題なくインストールできました。

```
$ gem install puma -v '2.15.3'
Fetching: puma-2.15.3.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed puma-2.15.3
1 gem installed
```

なので、可能であればpumaのバージョンを上げる、というのが一つの解決策になるかもしれません。

また、pumaのバージョンが上げられないのであれば、一度Ruby 2.0.0-p481を再インストールしてからpumaをインストールすると状況が改善するかもしれません。（こちらはちょっと当てずっぽうな提案ですが）

### EDIT

> ​バージョン指定せずにインストールした際に、どのバージョンがインストールされるのかという情報はどこに載っているのでしょうか？

公式ドキュメントを探せば載っているかもしれませんが、ちょっと調べていません。
おそらくこういう動きになっていると思います。（`bundle install`した場合を想定）

#### 1. Gemfile.lockに対象のgemが記載されている場合

Gemfile.lockで指定されているバージョンがインストールされる

#### 2. Gemfile.lockに対象のgemが記載されていない、またはGemfile.lock自体がない場合

同じRubyバージョンですでにそのgemがローカルマシンに存在し、かつ他のgemとの依存関係面でも問題がない場合、そのgemが使われる。

それ以外の場合は、依存関係上問題のない範囲でそのgemの最新版がダウンロード＆インストールされる。

ただし、Gemfile内でバージョンが指定されていれば（`gem 'puma', '2.15.3'`等）、指定されたバージョンのgemがインストールされる。

---

ただし、僕の経験上たぶんこうだろうと考えているだけで公式な情報ではありません。
正確に知りたい場合は自分でちゃんと調べた方が良いと思います。

Comment: ご回答有難う御座います。最新の2.15にすれば、問題なくインストールできました。しかし、疑問なのは、当初にやっていた、バーションを指定せずにgem install puma とやった際に、なぜ最新のバージョンがインストールされないかです。私の中のイメージでは、バージョンを指定しない限りは最新のバージョンがインストールされると思っていたのでびっくりでした。（勉強にもなりました）改めて、pumaのgithubを見なしていたのですが、結局この疑問は解決しませんでした・・・。pumaに限らずですが、バージョン指定せずにインストールした際に、どのバージョンがインストールされるのかという情報はどこに載っているのでしょうか？

https://github.com/puma/puma


宜しければご教授頂けると幸いです。度々申し訳ありません。

Comment: 再度ご回答いただきましてありがとうございます！今回のケースではGemfile.lockにpuma (2.11.0)と指定されていたのが原因？みたいでした。

Gemfileの方では、バージョン指定されていなかったため特に問題視してませんでしたが、Gemfile.lockもきちんと確認すべきでした（むしろGemfile.lockのほうが重要ですね）・・・。

いい勉強になりました。ご丁寧に有りがとうございます。