# Railsローカル環境構築にて、'puma'がインストールできないエラー「error occurred while installing puma (4.3.5)」

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Railsローカル環境構築をする際に、pumaのインストールで躓いております。

```
An error occurred while installing puma (4.3.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install puma -v '4.3.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

※環境構築手順は下記ページなどを参考にしています。

- https://reasonable-code.com/ruby-on-rails-environment/
- https://qiita.com/kodai_0122/items/56168eaec28eb7b1b93b#comments

▼ローカル環境　※PC：MacBook Pro

```
$ brew --version
Homebrew 2.4.3

$ rbenv -v
rbenv 1.1.2

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.6p146

$ gem -v
3.0.3

$ bundler -v
Bundler version 2.1.4

$ rails -v
Rails 6.0.3.2

$ which openssl
/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/openssl

$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020

$ which sqlite3
/usr/local/opt/sqlite/bin/sqlite3

$ sqlite3 --version
3.32.3

※環境変数の設定状況
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
…
```

ーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー

調べていて色々と似たような問題について調査してみたのですが、
３日間ほど難航しており解決に至っておりません・・

- [yosemiteでpumaのgemがインストール出来ない。おそらくSSL周りのエラーですが、原因がわかりません。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/19430/40948)
- [RubyとRailsをインストール後、gem puma -v '3.11.3'のインストール方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/42847/40948)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/20294199
- https://teratail.com/questions/274272

念のためHomebrewからアンインストールし、再インストールして実施ましたが、
上記 puma のエラーは再発してしまいます・・

吐き出しているログを確認してみましたが、解読が難しく対処方法がわからない状況です・・

> Results logged to /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.6.0/puma-4.3.5/gem_make.out

どなたか原因がわかる方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご助言いただけないでしょうか。
何卒、よろしくお願いいたします。

▼rails newした際のエラー

```
[bash ./0706] $ rails new app

・
・
・
Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
Using listen 3.2.1
Using method_source 1.0.0
Fetching puma 4.3.5
Installing puma 4.3.5 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/ext/puma_http11
/Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/ruby -I /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200706-4897-1qebpfx.rb
extconf.rb --with-opt-dir\=/usr/local/opt/openssl
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... yes
checking for openssl/bio.h... yes
checking for DTLS_method() in openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for TLS_server_method() in openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version in openssl/ssl.h... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR="
compiling http11_parser.c
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:44:18: warning: unused variable 'puma_parser_en_main' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const int puma_parser_en_main = 1;
                 ^
1 warning generated.
compiling io_buffer.c
compiling mini_ssl.c
mini_ssl.c:145:7: warning: unused variable 'min' [-Wunused-variable]
  int min, ssl_options;
      ^
mini_ssl.c:299:40: warning: function 'raise_error' could be declared with attribute 'noreturn' [-Wmissing-noreturn]
void raise_error(SSL* ssl, int result) {
                                       ^
2 warnings generated.
compiling puma_http11.c
puma_http11.c:203:22: error: implicitly declaring library function 'isspace' with type 'int (int)' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  while (vlen > 0 && isspace(value[vlen - 1])) vlen--;
                     ^
puma_http11.c:203:22: note: include the header <ctype.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'isspace'
1 error generated.
make: *** [puma_http11.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.6.0/puma-4.3.5/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing puma (4.3.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install puma -v '4.3.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  puma
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
       rails  webpacker:install
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
[bash ./0706] $
```

▼生成されたGemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.6'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.2'
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

※エラーの際に「Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4)'」と言われますが、
　作成されたGemfileには「gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'」の記載がある為
　bundle installすると'sqlite3'については消えました。

しかし'puma'はダメです・・
▼rails new後、bundle installした際のエラー

```
[bash ./app] $ bundle install

・
・
・
Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
Using listen 3.2.1
Using method_source 1.0.0
Fetching puma 4.3.5
Installing puma 4.3.5 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/ext/puma_http11
/Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/ruby -I /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200706-5109-1rhex2m.rb
extconf.rb --with-opt-dir\=/usr/local/opt/openssl
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... yes
checking for openssl/bio.h... yes
checking for DTLS_method() in openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for TLS_server_method() in openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version in openssl/ssl.h... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR="
compiling http11_parser.c
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:44:18: warning: unused variable 'puma_parser_en_main' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const int puma_parser_en_main = 1;
                 ^
1 warning generated.
compiling io_buffer.c
compiling mini_ssl.c
mini_ssl.c:145:7: warning: unused variable 'min' [-Wunused-variable]
  int min, ssl_options;
      ^
mini_ssl.c:299:40: warning: function 'raise_error' could be declared with attribute 'noreturn' [-Wmissing-noreturn]
void raise_error(SSL* ssl, int result) {
                                       ^
2 warnings generated.
compiling puma_http11.c
puma_http11.c:203:22: error: implicitly declaring library function 'isspace' with type 'int (int)' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  while (vlen > 0 && isspace(value[vlen - 1])) vlen--;
                     ^
puma_http11.c:203:22: note: include the header <ctype.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'isspace'
1 error generated.
make: *** [puma_http11.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.6.0/puma-4.3.5/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing puma (4.3.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install puma -v '4.3.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  puma
[bash ./app] $
```

「gem install puma -v '4.3.5'ができるか確認して」と言われるので・・

▼gem install puma -v '4.3.5'を実行した際のエラー

```
[bash ./~] $ gem install puma -v '4.3.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing puma:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/ext/puma_http11
/Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/ruby -I /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200706-5247-aj1e4q.rb extconf.rb
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... yes
checking for openssl/bio.h... yes
checking for DTLS_method() in openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for TLS_server_method() in openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version in openssl/ssl.h... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR="
compiling http11_parser.c
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:44:18: warning: unused variable 'puma_parser_en_main' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const int puma_parser_en_main = 1;
                 ^
1 warning generated.
compiling io_buffer.c
compiling mini_ssl.c
mini_ssl.c:145:7: warning: unused variable 'min' [-Wunused-variable]
  int min, ssl_options;
      ^
mini_ssl.c:299:40: warning: function 'raise_error' could be declared with attribute 'noreturn' [-Wmissing-noreturn]
void raise_error(SSL* ssl, int result) {
                                       ^
2 warnings generated.
compiling puma_http11.c
puma_http11.c:203:22: error: implicitly declaring library function 'isspace' with type 'int (int)' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  while (vlen > 0 && isspace(value[vlen - 1])) vlen--;
                     ^
puma_http11.c:203:22: note: include the header <ctype.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'isspace'
1 error generated.
make: *** [puma_http11.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.6.0/puma-4.3.5/gem_make.out
[bash ./~] $
```

※最初にも記載しましたが・・・
ログを確認してみましたが、上記吐き出された内容と同様でした。解読が難しく対処方法がわからない状況です・・
Results logged to /Users/yamaryo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.6.0/puma-4.3.5/gem_make.out

Comment: 4.3.5周辺のバージョンで同じエラーに遭遇している人がいるようです。https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/2286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コンパイルの必要なGemのインストールで失敗する時は
Xcodeのバージョンが原因のことがよくあるので一度Xcodeを最新にしてから

```
gem install puma -v '4.3.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

でもう一度`puma`のインストールを試してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

＞ironsand様
　Xcodeをインストールして、もう一度やりなおしたところ
　無事、rails new後にbundle installが成功しました！
　ありがとうございます！これで先に進めます！！

※Xcodeについて調べ直して気づいたのですが・・
　 そもそもXcodeのappをしっかりインストールしていなかった恐れがあります・・
　 Qiitaばかり見ているのですが、環境構築をhomebrewから開始する記事が多く
　 Xcodeのappを見落としていたのが原因だったのかもしれませんが、真の原因はよくわかりません・・

＞shingo.nakanishi様
　pumaのgit拝見しました。4.3.5はなんらかの最新のコミットを取りこぼしているようですね・・
　pumaのgitを参照することも大事なんですね。勉強になりました！情報ありがとうございます！

先輩方、ご回答ありがとうございました！
すみません、Xcodeインストール後やりなおしで
"puma 4.3.5"は無事にインストール完了できていたので
結局のところ私の環境準備不足だった恐れがあります(^^;)

進めてよかったです！
一人で悩んでいたので大変たすかりました！ありがとうございました！

```
$ bundle install
・
・
Using method_source 1.0.0
Using puma 4.3.5
Using rack-proxy 0.6.5
・
・
Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile dependencies, 74 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

▼インストール成功version

```
$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 11.5
Build version 11E608c

$ brew --version
Homebrew 2.4.3

$ rbenv version
2.6.6

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.6p146

$ gem -v
3.0.3

$ bundler -v
Bundler version 2.1.4

$ rails -v
Rails 6.0.3.2
```

Comment: うまくいったようでよかったです。環境構築周りは躓きやすいわりに初心者には解決が難しいことが多いので30分〜1時間ぐらい調べてエラーが解消しない時は気軽に質問をしてください。状況の整理にもなりますし。

Comment: ＞ironsand様
ありがとうございます！確かにおっしゃる通り状況の整理することで気づくこともあると勉強になりました！積極的に質問したいと思います！